# How to ask an API for many values (of the past 14 days) via iterative timestamp manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, api

I want to calculate the RSI - (Relative Strength Index)(Last 14 Days) for the Bitcoin-Price. The necessary data for the past 14 days comes from an API. The result should be stored in a variable for further processing. I tried different methods, but the result wasn´t working. I think i don´t found the right way to solve this. I was not able to create a complete and working result, so I am here to ask my first question on Stack Overflow.

> 1. How can I ask the API for the course of the past 14 days via 
>      iterative timestamp manipulation?

Timestamp now -1day/-2days.... (&ts=xxxxxxxxxxxx) - example: (ts=1452680400)

`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD&ts=1452680400`

> 2. How can i put the values from the API in an array?:

```
var closePrices= {
    var  : 'text',
    array: [BTCDay1, BTCDay2, BTCDay3, BTCDay4, BTCDay5, BTCDay6, BTCDay7, BTCDay8, BTCDay9, BTCDay10, BTCDay11, BTCDay12, BTCDay13, BTCDay14]
};
```

> 3. Then I want to put the array in this calculation formular:

```
public static double CalculateRsi(IEnumerable<double> closePrices)
    {
        var prices = closePrices as double[] ?? closePrices.ToArray();

        double sumGain = 0;
        double sumLoss = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < prices.Length; i++)
        {
            var difference = prices[i] - prices[i - 1];
            if (difference >= 0)
            {
                sumGain += difference;
            }
            else
            {
                sumLoss -= difference;
            }
        }

        if (sumGain == 0) return 0;
        if (Math.Abs(sumLoss) < Tolerance) return 100;

        var relativeStrength = sumGain / sumLoss;

        return 100.0 - (100.0 / (1 + relativeStrength));
    }
```

Comment: Step 1 presumably you need to make 14 queries, once for each day. And change the timestamp accordingly. You can use JS Date functionality to get timestamps. Step 2 we don't know what the returned data from the API looks like in order to know how to transform it, perhaps it is even already in an array, if it comes back as JSON. And the code in step 3 looks like C#, not JavaScript. So presumably you'll need to send your data to the server via ajax or postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several quite broad questions (it usually works better if you post some of the code you already tried to write yourself)... But fun ones to solve.

Assuming we can use es6 syntax, Promises and fetch (if you can't, look up how to polyfill & transpile).

### Creating an array of timestamps

To get a timestamp for the current date, you write `Date.now()`. To change this time stamp to a day `n` days ago, we decrease it by the number of milliseconds in a day:

```
const timeStampForDaysAgo = 
  nrOfDays => Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * nrOfDays;

// e.g.: yesterday
const yesterday = timeStampForDaysAgo(1);
```

Now, if we fill an array of the integers `0...14`, we can use `map` to create an array of timestamps!

```
const lastTwoWeeks = Array.from(Array(14), (_, i) => timeStampForDaysAgo(i))
```

### Doing the requests

In modern browsers, you can use `fetch` to do requests. We'll need a list of URLs though, not just timestamps. To make the URLs, we again use `map`:

```
const urls = lastTwoWeeks.map(ts => `https://your-url.com?ts=${ts}`);
```

Now that we have URLs, we can create our requests (again, using `map`):

```
const btcRequests = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()));
```

### Calculating the result

We can't start calculating the result until all requests have finished. That's where `Promise.all` comes in:

```
Promise.all(btcRequests).then(calcRSI);
```

This makes sure we only call `calcRSI` until *all* requests have finished.

Because the API returns objects of `{ BTC: { USD: Number } }`, we'll have to extract the numbers before we can do our math.

```
Promise
  .all(btcRequests)
  .then(responses => responses.map(obj => obj.BTC.USD))
```

Now that we have an array of numbers, we can finally call the calculate function you gave in C# code. Of course, you'll have to translate it to javascript first.

```
const calcRSI = (arrayOfValues) => /* do math, return value */

Promise
  .all(btcRequests)
  .then(responses => responses.map(obj => obj.BTC.USD))
  .then(calcRSI)
  .then(rsi => console.log("The RSI for the last 14 days, is:", rsi);
```

See the code in action in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9m9t78k/) (make sure to open the console)

Comment: Wow! Great thanks for that! I try to understand this completely, but I am not familiar with Lambda functions. The result looks good, but is switching when the page is reloaded. Is there a way to cut this down to a accuracy in "hour"? I am really fascinated by the solution :)

Comment: To make the time stamps go back `x` hours, you remove the `24` from the `timeStampForDaysAgo` function. Make sure you don't do too many API requests at once though... There might be an endpoint in the service that gives you multiple data-points at once?

Comment: Yes i think its better to use this API-Request with (close-prices):
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=14
But then the script needs to be changed a bit, actually i am trying this - But thats really a hard challenge.

Comment: Definitely! Nice find!